# Counting calendar weeks and store them into an array with .isocalendar

Tags: python, arrays, datetime

so I got a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{2321: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 11, 55, 50, 414175, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2322: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 10, 17, 338086, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2323: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 12, 30, 847941, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2324: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 15, 14, 803438, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2325: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 17, 42, 749529, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2326: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 19, 58, 757024, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2327: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 22, 16, 554052, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2328: datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 16, 13, 26, 56, 4452, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2081: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27, 10, 28, 10, 695887, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2082: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27, 10, 35, 34, 71091, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>), 
2083: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27, 10, 40, 1, 436955, tzinfo=<LocalTimezone "UTC+01:00" 1:00:00>)}
```

its {ticketID:ticketDateTime}

i'd like to use .isocalendar to get calendarweeks from the DateTime-objects (because i need to count tickets for every week)

i've thought about creating an array filled with zeros with the length 52 (because a year has 52 weeks), then iterate through the dictionary with a forloop and always add 1 to the index of this calendarweek.

sorry, I am new in python and will try to show you some code in C#, how i think it could work:

```
int[] resultsArray = new int[52]

for(int i = 0; i<= myDictionary.Length; i++){
index = myDictionary[i].isocalendar()[1]
resultsArray[index] = resultsArray[index]+1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ClosedList = [0] * 53
OpenList = [0] * 53
OpenedList = [0] * 53
def CreateKWlist():
for i in ClosedDict:
    for j,k in ClosedDict[i]['prio-events']:
        if j.isocalendar()[0] == 2015:
            index = j.isocalendar()[1]
            ClosedList[index] += 1
            OpenedList[index] += 1
            break
for i in OpenDict:
    for j,k in OpenDict[i]['prio-events']:
        if j.isocalendar()[0] == 2015:
            index = j.isocalendar()[1]
            OpenList[index] += 1
            OpenedList[index] += 1
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Counter` to do this. https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects

```
c = Counter()
for d in dates:
    c[d.week] += 1  # note I don't know the syntax for week off the top of my head
```